# How do i access the nested dictionaries in python

Tags: python

please help me accessing the nested dictionaries:

```
moo = {'dell': {'strength': {}, 'weakness': {}},'ibm': {'strength': {}, 'weakness': {}}}
```

i can access the parent keys by using:

```
for k in moo.keys():
    print k
```

How do i access the child keys??

Comment: Realize `moo[k]` is a dictionary as well, and that you're looping through a dictionary in that snippet you've got there

Comment: I want to access the second set of keys, the child keys

Comment: Read pascalhein's answer and see if my hint makes sense now.

Comment: As a side note, you don't have to, and shouldn't, use `.keys()` here. If you just write `for k in moo:`, that iterates the keys. In Python 3.x, there's not much difference, but in 2.x, by using `.keys()` you're forcing it to create a list (wasting time and memory) for no reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just loop through each item:

```
for k in moo.keys():
    print k # 1st level key
    for sk in moo[k].keys():
        print sk # 2nd level subkey
```

This should print

```
ibm
weakness
strength
dell
weakness
strength
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the the [`dict.items()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) method!

```
for maker, properties in moo.items():
    for property, values in properties.items():
        print(maker, property, values)
```

Outputs:

```
dell strength {}
dell weakness {}
ibm strength {}
ibm weakness {}
```

To access a single element just chain the `[key]`-calls:

```
moo['dell']['strength']
```

Outputs:

```
{}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use nested for loops:

```
for k in moo:
    for i in k.keys():
        print i
```

Or to access them directly:

```
moo['dell']['strength']
```

Comment: `k` is the key. This will not work because `k` (a string) does not have a method `keys`.

Comment: Noted, I misunderstood the question.